# Manual for Presentation typesetting in ConTeXt

Tags: context, presentations

Is there a manual similar to the Beamer manual but for presentation in ConTeXt?

I found this: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Presentations

but I feel it lacks many information, for example on navigation systems and themes.

I also found some blog articles but they seem more focused on specific aspects and many of them are very old.

Comment: The emphasis in ConTeXt is to create your own style rather than use some prespecified  as in LaTeX. Creating a presentation style is relatively simple; see for example [this blog post](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/creating-a-clean-presentation-style-in-40-commits/). If you want ready made styles, look at the [simpleslides](http://modules.contextgarden.net/simpleslides) module.